# LinqToSql overriding insert with inner classes C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a base recipe class and I am using a datacontext. I overrode the insert method for the recipe in the datacontext and am trying to insert into its children. Nomatter what I do I cannot get the child to insert.Currently, just the recipe inserts and nothing happens with the child.

```
    partial void InsertRecipe(Recipe instance)
    {
        // set up the arrays
        for (int x = 0; x < instance.PlainIngredients.Count; ++x)
        {
            instance.TextIngredients.Add(new TextIngredient()
            {
                StepNumber = x + 1,
                Text = instance.PlainIngredients[x]
            });
        }

        this.ExecuteDynamicInsert(instance);
    }
```

I have tried everything I can think of. I even instantiated another datacontext in the method and after the instance came back from ExecuteDynamicInsert with the id, tried to add it, and I get timeout errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Override SubmitChanges in the DataContext, and find all of the inserts and updates that are recipes. Run the algorithm to add children there.

```
    public override void SubmitChanges(
        System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode failureMode)
    {
        ChangeSet changes = this.GetChangeSet();

        var recipeInserts = (from r in changes.Inserts
                       where (r as Recipe) != null
                       select r as Recipe).ToList<Recipe>();

        var recipeUpdates = (from r in changes.Updates
                       where (r as Recipe) != null
                       select r as Recipe).ToList<Recipe>();

        ConvertTextData(recipeInserts);
        ConvertTextData(recipeUpdates);

        base.SubmitChanges(failureMode);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The InsertX/UpdateX/DeleteX methods are called after LINQ to SQL has determined which objects will be included in SubmitChanges.

You would have been getting a timeout using two DataContext most likely because of locking issues between the two transactions.

I can't clearly make out what you are trying to achieve here - normally LINQ to SQL manages the child relationships itself - what are PlainIngredients and TextIngredients?